# Get video from database and displaying the video on a page directly without having to click a link

Tags: php, video

Working on a project that involves people signing up to the website and uploading a video, the thing is I have created a file upload form and it works perfectly, I head over to the database and check the users table and I see the video uploaded I then head into my PHP code and initialize the variable:

```
$Getvid = " ";
```

Then I fetch the row

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {  $vid = $row ["vid"]; }
```

After that I place

```
$Getvid = '< source src="user/'.$u.'/'.$vid.'" >';
if($vid == NULL) {
    $Getvid = '< source src="image/Movie on 2013-07-24 at 13.43.mov" type="video/mp4" >';
}
```

To get video files that a user have uploaded and echo it out on he/she page and also if the vid row is null then the script would show a default video that I have stored in the database

After that I echo out the video on the users page

```
      < video width="320" height="240" controls>
      < source src="< ?php echo $vid; ? > " >
      </video>
```

But for some reason the video doesn't show also the default doesn't work unless I source it specially like this:

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="image/Movie on 2013-07-24 at 13.43.mov" type="video/mp4"  >
    </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two potential sources of the problem, you shouldn't store your files with spaces in their names and you haven't specified a type for your video.

The SRC should contain a valid URL and therefore you should have %20 or + in your PHP string in stead of the spaces.

Note: As mentioned by Fisk, your php tags are wrong due to the spacing. You use the PHP echo short-form by replacing

```
< ?php echo $vid; ? > 
by 
<?= $vid; ?>
```

Comment: thanks for responding Tomb i actually don't have spaces in my actually tags but for some reason as i was explaining to fisk stackoverflow would show my code in the question without the spaces i do get a error on firebug when clicking play on the video player saying "Invalid URI. Load of media resource failed." could you give me a example of how i would write the solution properly cause i am  a beginner and am not knowledge a 100% on what the resolution is i will continue to do my research on  this tho,thanks again to both you and fisk

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not be invoked if you're actually typing `< ?php` in the source code. It will need to be in a single tag, such as `<?php`. When you have fixed that, compare the output from the PHP code with your working example and see where it differs. If you want a more exact answer on that, add the generated HTML together with the HTML you're expecting to your question.

You're also using the same variable in different paths; one place you're appending image/ before the video name, while your variable doesn't seem to contain the path.

Comment: hi fisk thanks for responding to my question,the "image" that is appending in my src is the folder in which i have the default video stored also sorry about the spaces in my php tags in my actually code there are no space but for some reason when i was putting my question together on stackoverflow  the information between the "< >" disappeared when i had it like this "<?php echo $vid; ?>" and when i insert the space it showed  how would i had a path to my variable? would this be a example of adding a path $Getvid = $_GET ['vid']; am a beginner so forgive my lack of knowledge